# extjs login page

Tags: extjs, authentication

I created Aspx login page and ext js login form in it

ExtJs code

```
 Ext.onReady(function () {

            var loginForm = Ext.create('Ext.FormPanel', {
                id: 'login-form',
                url:"Login.aspx",
                method: 'POST',
                renderTo: container,
                frame: true,
                title: 'Login to EvalueX',
                bodyPadding: '5px 5px 0',
                bodyStyle: 'padding:15px;background:transparent',
                width: 450,
                fieldDefaults: {
                    labelWidth: 125,
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    autoFitErrors: false
                },
                defaults: {
                    width: 300
                },
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [
                    {
                        fieldLabel: 'User Name',
                        name: 'user',
                        id: 'user',
                        allowBlank: false
                    },
                    {
                        fieldLabel: 'Password',
                        name: 'pass',

                        allowBlank: false // id of the initial password field
                    }
                ]
                 ,
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Login',
                    id: 'btnLogin',
                    handler: function () {
                        if (loginForm.getForm().isValid()) {
                            url: "Login.aspx",

                            Ext.getCmp('btnLogin').disable();
                            loginForm.getForm().submit({
                                method: 'POST',

                                // waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',

                                // or using a progress bar

                                failure: function (form, action) {
                                    Ext.getCmp('btnLogin').enable();
                                    showLoadingImage(false);
                                    alert(action.result.errors.reason);
                                }

                            });
                        }
                        // Ext.getCmp('login-form').getForm().submit({ waitMsg: 'Please wait...' });
                    }
                }
                ]
            });


        });
```

Aspx. Code it's simple Server.Transer.

I receive an error ."You are trying to decode invalid json "

Sumbit Request does not arrive to server

But when I referrence to different aspx page that the page the load form is placed 
it's working

Comment: `Sumbit Request does not arrive to server` => that's the error message you are getting?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I highlty doubt it

Comment: @Jaitsu, me too. That's why I asked. So that I know whether this question would require magic skills in order to be answered. Skills allowing to read other people's minds for example.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yeah it would be great if it was a little more descriptive, I'm betting that 'Login.aspx' isn't the correct URL

Comment: you say the submit request never arrives at the server, yet you receive "you are trying to decode invalid json" error? So it arrives okay at the server?

Comment: if (loginForm.getForm().isValid()) {
                            url: "Login.aspx",

isn't it an invalid js first of all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a separate asp and submit the file and it's worked ok

Answer (score 0):

It's seems in the code you given that the success event is not handled and there is no code with a decode of the json result. Something missing...

In fact, your code doesn't help much, exept saying "verify that the adress to the "Login.aspx" page is correct" ?

Comment: Did someone did aspx page, put in the page panenform and on submit